# Open new view after facebook logon

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

I'm a newbie in Objective-C and I have some problems.

I have implemented facebook auth in my single view application following the official facebook tutorial. All works fine - my button appears and I can login/logout.

But after the connection to facebook I want to open an other view. So I created a new view controller in my builder, put a new segue(with a name)
But when I call it with `performSegueWithIdentifier` that new view controller cannot be opened.

So if someone can help me it will be great.
Thank you all of you by advance ;)

Comment: Do you have compile errors or runtime errors? What's printed in your console? Are you sure you have set the right identifier to the segue? Show us some code!

Comment: I have this error "-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)" but in the facebook doc they say its just a warning" and i use the good segue

Comment: sorry for my question but how i can put code here

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code. You will find help about how to embed code by clicking the question mark on the top right corner of the text field frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Next"  sender:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Next"  sender:self];
}
```

Where's the code of your button?

If I take a look at this code, you want to go to the next screen immediately after **showing** your button on screen.

You may want to respond to some Facebook's class interfaces. Look for the Facebook SDK.